# How to continue a script after X has been closed?

Tags: shell-script, x11, raspberry-pi

I recently installed RetroPie on my Raspberry Pi and I'm trying to find a way to (once I'm in LXDE) run a shell script that kills X and then starts EmulationStation. I can kill X with `pkill x` but then running `emulationstation` doesn't do anything. I'm new to Bash so I'm not quite sure what to do next. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Probably your session is being killed together with your xterm when you kill X.

Try using `nohup` to protect your commands from disappearing terminals (the "hup" in "nohup" stands for "hangup", which could happen back in the day when you dialed into a Unix system via a modem and the modem connection died, or in other words the telephone line was hung up).

```
$ nohup sh -c "pkill X; emulationstation" &
```

The `&` puts the whole command in the background, and `nohup` starts a shell to run the command given within the quotes, while "immunizing" that shell from the disappearing terminal.

Comment: This didn't work for me :/ I selected "Execute" instead of "Execute in Terminal" when LXDE prompted me when I ran the script (double-clicked on the desktop).

Comment: You can put the command line I gave in a script and run that.

Comment: I did just that.